# Is "pulled down" an appropriate phrasal verb to use here?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-choice

He angrily pulled down a big bookcase.

Question:

Is "pulled down" an appropriate phrasal verb to use here to mean he forcibly tipped over the bookcase?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically this is--of course--correct, but "pulled down" is a little awkward.

Alternatives could be:

"tipped over" -> this might imply too much care

"pushed/shoved/knocked over"

"brought down"

Comment: Or 'pulled over'.